# i want to incorporate Head and Body in handlebars (node.js)

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

i want to encorporate my head and my body on handlebars, but i dont know how,

i will give an example on how im using it '''

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index.css">
<h1> test</h1>
```

'''
the handlebars'''

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/nome.css">
    <title>Documen</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{{body}}}
</body>
</html>
```

'''

with this code im passing that every element go to this {{{body}}} right?
and i want to pass a head too, how do i do that?

really sorry if the question is confuse, i really dont know how to explain better

Comment: Did the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly You need install `npm install express express-handlebars`.
Here you have folder and file project structure:

[image]

---

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// view engine setup
app.engine(
  "hbs",
  exphbs.engine({
    defaultLayout: "main",
    extname: ".hbs",
  })
);

app.set("view engine", "hbs");

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("home");
});

app.get("/about", (req, res) => {
  res.render("about");
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node Server running on port: http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

---

main.hbs

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{>header}}

    <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column" style="height: 800px;">
        {{{body}}}
        {{>mainContent}}
    </div>


    {{>footer}}
    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

header.hbs

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/about">about</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

---

mainContent.hbs

```
<h2>Hello World from Handlebars</h2>
<h3>Express</h3>
<h4>Bootstrap 5</h4>
```

---

footer.hbs

```
<footer>
    <p class="text-center text-muted">&copy; Copyright 2021 The Awesome Stuff</p>
</footer>
```

---

home.hbs

```
<h1>Home Page</h1>
```

---

about.hbs

```
<h1>About Page</h1>
```

---

Output:

[image]

*"express": "^4.17.1","express-handlebars": "^6.0.2"*